# Oracle OLS LBACSYS Errors

Tags: oracle, security, label

I'm learning the OLS (Oracle Label Security) feature of Oracle, and here is my problem.

I executed those procedures to enabled the OLS feature. My current user was `sys` who have the `sysdba` privilege.

```
EXEC LBACSYS.CONFIGURE_OLS;
EXEC LBACSYS.OLS_ENFORCEMENT.ENABLE_OLS;
```

Then I logged in by LBACSYS account to create the OLS Policy, but it not worked.

```
CONN LBACSYS/LBACSYS;
BEGIN
SA_SYSDBA.CREATE_POLICY (
     policy_name      => 'emp_ols_pol',
     column_name      => 'ols_col',
     default_options  => 'read_control, update_control');
END;
/
```

Error messages

```
Error report -
ORA-65109: operation not allowed in CDB$ROOT
ORA-06512: at "LBACSYS.LBAC_LGSTNDBY_UTIL", line 100
ORA-06512: at "LBACSYS.LBAC_SYSDBA", line 80
ORA-06512: at "LBACSYS.LBAC_SYSDBA", line 138
ORA-06512: at "LBACSYS.LBAC_LGSTNDBY_UTIL", line 76
ORA-06512: at "LBACSYS.SA_SYSDBA", line 16
ORA-06512: at line 2
65109. 00000 -  "operation not allowed in CDB$ROOT"
*Cause:    An operation was attempted that is not supported in the Container
           Database root.
*Action:   Switch to a pluggable database to perform the operation.
```

Help me please, and thank you guys a lot!

Comment: This question is not about programming problem. I think it would be better to ask it on [dba.stackexchange.com](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: It has not worked for me in the main instance, create it in another instance and follow the steps.